# How to create a serial port by boost::asio and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port

At first, I'm not an expert c++ programming and my question might be very elementary.

I am trying to use boost asio to access serial port and using shared_ptr to prevent memory leak. I searched some sample codes but for me, simply many of them don't work.

my code is as follow:

SerialPortConnection.cpp:

```
#include "SerialPortConnection.h"
SerialPortConnection::SerialPortConnection( std::string port_name_init, int baud_rate_init,
        boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size        charSize_init,
        boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits             stopBit_init,
        boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity                pariy_init,
        boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control          flowControl_init)        :
        port_name(port_name_init),
        baud_rate(baud_rate_init),
        charSize(charSize_init),
        stopBit(stopBit_init),
        pariy(pariy_init),
        flowControl(flowControl_init)
{
port = boost::shared_ptr<serial_port_ptr>( new boost::asio::serial_port );
}
SerialPortConnection::~SerialPortConnection()
{
    //dtor
}
```

SerialPortConnection.h:

```
#ifndef SERIALPORTCONNECTION_H
#define SERIALPORTCONNECTION_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
//using namespace::boost::asio;
class SerialPortConnection
{
public:
    SerialPortConnection( std::string port_name_init, int baud_rate_init,
                          boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size        charSize000_init,
                          boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits             stopBit000_init,
                          boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity                pariy000_init,
                          boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control          flowControl_init );
    virtual ~SerialPortConnection();
private:
    std::string port_name;
    int baud_rate;
    boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size        charSize;
    boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits             stopBit;
    boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity                pariy;
    boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control          flowControl;
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    typedef boost::asio::serial_port* serial_port_ptr;
    boost::shared_ptr < serial_port_ptr > port;
};
#endif // SERIALPORTCONNECTION_H
```

Compiler creates compile error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in test-1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/mkh/cb-codes/test-prjs/test-1/src/SerialPortConnection.cpp||In constructor ‘SerialPortConnection::SerialPortConnection(std::__cxx11::string, int, boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size, boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits, boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity, boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control)’:|
/home/mkh/cb-codes/test-prjs/test-1/src/SerialPortConnection.cpp|17|error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::basic_serial_port<>::basic_serial_port()’|
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_serial_port.hpp|147|note: candidate: boost::asio::basic_serial_port<SerialPortService>::basic_serial_port(boost::asio::basic_serial_port<SerialPortService>&&) [with SerialPortService = boost::asio::serial_port_service]|
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_serial_port.hpp|147|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_serial_port.hpp|126|note: candidate: boost::asio::basic_serial_port<SerialPortService>::basic_serial_port(boost::asio::io_service&, const native_handle_type&) [with SerialPortService = boost::asio::serial_port_service; boost::asio::basic_serial_port<SerialPortService>::native_handle_type = int]|
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_serial_port.hpp|126|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided|
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_serial_port.hpp|105|note: candidate: boost::asio::basic_serial_port<SerialPortService>::basic_serial_port(boost::asio::io_service&, const string&) [with SerialPortService = boost::asio::serial_port_service; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]|
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_serial_port.hpp|105|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided|
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_serial_port.hpp|85|note: candidate: boost::asio::basic_serial_port<SerialPortService>::basic_serial_port(boost::asio::io_service&, const char*) [with SerialPortService = boost::asio::serial_port_service]|
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_serial_port.hpp|85|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided|
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_serial_port.hpp|69|note: candidate: boost::asio::basic_serial_port<SerialPortService>::basic_serial_port(boost::asio::io_service&) [with SerialPortService = boost::asio::serial_port_service]|
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_serial_port.hpp|69|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

I've tried various solutions. for example I added this one to SerialPortConnection.h:

boost::asio::serial_port    port0;

but also it doesn't work. It actually leads to another compile error.
Now I need to know how to create a serial port with shared_ptr.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your error message. `no matching function for call to...`

There is no constructor for `serial_port` that takes zero arguments. You need to pass the likes of an io_service. Here are the constructors.

[basic_serial_port documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_serial_port/basic_serial_port.html)

So you would:

```
port = boost::shared_ptr<serial_port_ptr>( boost::make_shared< boost::asio::serial_port >(io_service_));
```

Note the use of `'make_shared` rather than `new`.

And here is an example that compiles

[SerialPort class sample using boost::asio::serial_port](https://gist.github.com/yoggy/3323808)

Answer (score 2):

shared_ptr is unnecessary. Here a code snippet:

```
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>

class SerialPortConnection
{
public:
   SerialPortConnection();

private:
   boost::asio::io_service    m_ioService;  //order is important so that m_ioService gets constructed first
   boost::asio::serial_port   m_port;
};

SerialPortConnection::SerialPortConnection()
: m_port(m_ioService)
{
   boost::system::error_code ec;  // choice: without ec Boost.Asio may throw

   m_port.open("COM1", ec);

   if (!ec)
   {
       boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate baud_rate1(9600);   
       m_port.set_option(baud_rate1);

      //etc.
   }
}
```

Be aware that Boost.Asio primarily uses an asynchronous model. It supports synchronous operations as well but not with a timeout (which is a dominant use case) and it's cumbersome to mimic that behavior.

Comment: The code will be extended in future and it seems that one of the solutions for garbage collection is shared_ptr. However your solution works very well and in some other projects will be used. Thanks!